# How to add id to button add to woocomerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

someone knows how I can add id to the woocommerce buttons, woocommerce adds this structure

```
<button type="submit" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="id_del_producto" 
    class="button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple" >
       Agregar al Carrito
</button>
```

But do not add an ID to the buttons, I would like to know how you could add the product id to the id of the button, that is, if the product id is `604` to add an `id = "id604"` or similar to the button so that the structure that generates

```
<button type="submit" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="id_del_producto" 
    class="button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple" id="id604">
     Agregar al Carrito
</button>
```

this has to be on all the buttons, I think I have to modify the `add-to-cart.php` file but I don't know how to do it, I'm not very good at php, I appreciate your answers, thanks!

Comment: @RamRaider Hi, sorry, I asked the question in the wrong language, I already corrected it

Comment: no problem - perhaps add `add-to-cart.php` if you think that is where the code needs to be changed?

Comment: @RamRaider Well, it would have to be there because it has to be on all the buttons, I really don't know

Comment: Like you I don't know either having never used `woo-commerce` but others may know..

Comment: @RamRaider I understand, anyway thank you for commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its not the `add_to_cart.php` try `simple.php` you will find all buttons variations in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart` or if you are using a theme supporting woocommerce try to find it in your theme's woocommerce folder.

Then you simply add this line of code `id="id<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>"`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I am using a puglin to add the amount in the woocommerce buttons, so it does not have the template, in the end I solved it with this

<button type="submit" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="' . $product->id . '" class="button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple" id="add-' . $product->id . '">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>